# How to extract year only from email date

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I'm reading an entire Gmail emails (inbox/sent/trash...), and try to create folders in google drive according to dates.

So folders should be categorized like (...,2019,2020, 2021). Each folder contains all emails in this year in my Gmail.

I managed to create the folders, getting messages through using Threads, all these things works fine, but I couldn't extract the year of the message only.

As when I use `Threads[0].getMessages()[0].getDate()` what is returned is **[date and time of this message.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getDate())** which I can't extract the year only from it.

- I tried to split the date, but this is not string.
- I tried to make smth like `Threads[0].getMessages()[0].getDate().getYear()` it returned **120**!!!
- I tried to see if I can access it as an array, [index], it returned null
- I tried to parse it to Date(), but I couldn't get use of it too.

Is there is anyway that allows me to extract only the year from this format.

---

This is part of the script where i'm trying to fetch the date I'm using.

```
function GetAttachmentsWithTime() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));
    var start = 0;
    var end = 10;
    var filter = "has:attachment";
    var threads = GmailApp.search(filter,start,end);
    Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages()[0].getDate())
}
```

Comment: The issue could be that you need Threads[0].getMessages()[0].getDate().getYear().... round brackets after getMessages. If that does not solve it, I'd suggest posting the script here. Easier to catch the issue with more details.

Comment: sry this is type, already got the brackets after getMessages, i'll update the question with correct type and the script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the V8 runtime?

If so, see [this migration guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime/migration). It says:

> In the V8 runtime, Date.prototype.getYear() returns the year minus
> 1900 instead as required by ECMAScript standards.

So emails from the year 2020 would return 120 (i.e. 2020 - 1900 = 120).

To fix this, use `.getFullYear()`:

> When migrating your script to V8, always use
> Date.prototype.getFullYear(), which returns a four-digit year
> regardless of the date.